# Why is the probability of a microstate independent of its energy in Boltzmann statistics?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Intuitively, I would think that the bigger the energy, the less probable it is to have a particle in this microstate, but Boltzmann hypothesis is that the probability of all microstates is the same. It looks strange, doesn't it?

Then, there is a second problem: despite this hypothesis,
Boltzmann finds that a microstate $i$ has
$$
n_i
~=~
g_i \exp\left(-\alpha -\beta E_i\right)
$$
particles, where:

- $n_i$ is the number of particles in microstate $i ;$
- $E_i$ is the energy of microstate $i ;$
- $g_i$ is the degeneracy of a given cell $i .$

The conclusion that $n_i$ varies with $E_i$ seems to contradict the premise that the probability of a microstate doesn't vary with energy.

Thus, it looks like *contradictory* with the hypothesis that all microstates have the same probability: if they have the same probability, we should find the same number of particles in each cell, independently of energy.

Comment: Your assumption is erroneous, there is no such hypothesis. Only states of same energy are often assumed to have the same probability.

Comment: Thank you Jan. Here is a link that gives a sentence compatible with my question. What is your opinion ? Page 2, second paragraph of : http://www.yorku.ca/renef/boltzmann.pdf : "Boltzmann assumed that, for a given N and E, all microstates with energies epsilon_k that add up to E are equally probable."

Comment: No, you misunderstood that, probably because of poor wording. All microstates with energy $E$ are equally probable. Microstate does not have energy $\epsilon_k$. The author meant to say that however the energy $E$ is realized, that realization has certain probability and all such realizations have the same probabilyt. The probability may depend on $E$ though.

Comment: I see Jan. I huge thank you : you have saved me a huge time : I was completely getting crazy by this apparent contradiction. Now, everything is clear on this point. Thank you again